# My nativescript application fails on start when using KitKat

Tags: javascript, android, nativescript

My question is can I use multiDex on nativescript applications and if I can what did I do wrong?

**Problem**

My nativescript app on KitKat gives me the "Unfortunately myApp has stopped working error" on start up but works fine on newer versions, and on ios. I have read the many other questions that seemed to have my same problem but they suggest the same setup for multiDex.

**Research**

My application was giving me a dexOverflow exception when trying to build on android. So I used these two links to set up multidexEnabled and this fixed my issue for newer android versions, but not for kitkat 4.4.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html 
https://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/android/advanced-topics/extend-application-activity

I have looked at node_modules dependencies and don't believe and I can pick and choose the googleplay services to reduce my method count so I don't even have to worry about multidex.
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

**Code**

**package.json**

```
{
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application",
  "repository": " giturl ",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "com.myApplicationID.www",
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "3.3.0"
    },
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "3.3.1"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~4.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "~4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "~4.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.2.5",
    "@angular/http": "~4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "~4.2.5",
    "email-validator": "^1.0.7",
    "nativescript-angular": "4.2.0",
    "nativescript-appversion": "^1.4.1",
    "nativescript-cardview": "2.0.2",
    "nativescript-dom": "2.0.0",
    "nativescript-feedback": "^1.0.6",
    "nativescript-loading-indicator": "2.3.2",
    "nativescript-local-notifications": "^1.2.2",
    "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^5.1.1",
    "nativescript-pro-ui": "^3.2.0",
    "nativescript-pulltorefresh": "2.0.2",
    "nativescript-purchase": "1.0.4",
    "nativescript-social-share": "1.4.0",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "1.0.4",
    "nativescript-toast": "^1.4.6",
    "nativescript-unit-test-runner": "^0.3.4",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.4.3",
    "tns-core-modules": "^3.3.0",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.47",
    "babel-traverse": "6.22.1",
    "babel-types": "6.22.0",
    "babylon": "6.15.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.6.1",
    "karma": "^1.7.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-nativescript-launcher": "^0.4.0",
    "lazy": "1.0.11",
    "nativescript-dev-android-snapshot": "^0.*.*",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.4.6",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2"
  }
}
```

**app.gradle**

```
android {
        defaultConfig {
            generatedDensities = []
            applicationId = "com.myApplicationID.www"
            minSdkVersion 17
            targetSdkVersion 26
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        aaptOptions {
            additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
        }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

**androidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="__PACKAGE__"
    android:versionCode="60"
    android:versionName="2.21">

    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="__APILEVEL__"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:name="org.myApp.Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <activity
            android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_kimera"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme">

            <meta-data android:name="SET_THEME_ON_LAUNCH" android:resource="@style/AppTheme" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.tns.ErrorReportActivity"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**application.android.js**

```
var application = require("application");

var superProto = android.app.Application.prototype;
// the first parameter of the `extend` call defines the package and the name for the native *.JAVA file generated.
var Application = android.app.Application.extend("org.myApp.Application", {
    onCreate: function() {
        superProto.onCreate.call(this);

        // At this point modules have already been initialized

        // Enter custom initialization code here
    },
    attachBaseContext: function(base) {
        superProto.attachBaseContext.call(this, base);
        // This code enables MultiDex support for the application (if needed)
        android.support.multidex.MultiDex.install(this);
    }
});
```

I have also tried without application.android.js and setting manifest application name as

```
<application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

I'm sure I'm doing something simple wrong or have gone the wrong direction with this.

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html
https://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/android/advanced-topics/extend-application-activity

Had every answer I needed. I just needed to be more diligent!

The biggest problems I had

- knowing app.gradle is treated just like the build.gradle
- Putting the `multiDexKeepProguard

  file('../../multiDexKeepConfig.txt')` inside the default config of
  the app.gradle.
- using the wildcard for com.tns classes inside the multiDexKeepConfig.txt

**Solution**

**app.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}

android {
  defaultConfig {
    generatedDensities = []
    applicationId = "myappId"
        multiDexEnabled = true
        multiDexEnabled true
        multiDexKeepProguard file('../../multiDexKeepConfig.txt')
  }
  aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
  }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }
}
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
    def requested = details.requested
    if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
      if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
        details.useVersion '25.3.1'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**application.android.ts**

```
import * as application from "application";

// the `JavaProxy` decorator specifies the package and the name for the native *.JAVA file generated.
@JavaProxy("org.myApp.Application")
class Application extends android.app.Application {
    protected onCreate(): void {
        super.onCreate();

        // At this point modules have already been initialized
        // Enter custom initialization code here
    }

    protected attachBaseContext(baseContext: android.content.Context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(baseContext);

        // This code enables MultiDex support for the application (if needed)
        android.support.multidex.MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

**multiDexKeepConfig.txt**

```
-keep public class com.tns.ManualInstrumentation$Mode { *; }
-keep class com.tns.** { *; }
-keep class org.nativescript.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
```